# Dr. Knowledgeable will be making a ... this evening

Tags: word-choice

I'm solving MCQ of some English book practice, but I don't understand one of the correct answers and I would like to know the explanation for that.

The question was:

> Dr. Knowledgeable will be making a ... this evening.

a) lecture

b) sermon

c) speech

d) talk

and the right answer according to the book is c (speech). Then my question is why is could't be a lecture or a talk? (so what I can understand that sermon is most less relevant because normally it turns to pastors or sheikhs)

Comment: Idiomatically, you *make a speech*, you don't "make a lecture" or "make a talk".

Comment: Generally, it is expressed commonly as 'deliver a lecture ', 'give a talk' and 'make a speech '. The point mentioned about sermon is correct. So it may not be Included.

Comment: He could also _deliver_ or _give_ a speech. The answer to the question "Why couldn't it be a lecture or a talk?" is _Because that is not how we express this in English._ It's not bound by a "rule" of grammar, it's _idiomatic._ It's very important to understand the word [**idiom.**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/idiom)

Comment: Thank you all. I have learnt from your comments. I didn't know that idiomatically it goes together just with "make a speech". (deliver a lecture or give a talk.) It's absolutely interesting for me, because I used to deal with this words frequently.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is a case of idiomatic correctness; as one of the main idiomatic problems with learning English can be highlighted as other languages. As a natural English speaker, I see the other options as just wrong, and the answer would be:
**Dr. Knowledgeable is giving a __talk/lecture/sermon__.** This is idiomatic however, and to an English speaker, either option would be understandable, only feeling incorrect for the person hearing the given phrase.